# Home folder synced to HD: results differ!

Tags: command-line, permissions, disk-usage, rsync, cp

I'm new to Ubuntu. I would like to have an exact copy of my home folder on my Hard drive.

I've tried the following  (no programs running on Ubuntu):

1.
Copy-paste ~/ to /dest1/ per drag and drop in nautilus

--> du -s differs and diff -r ~/ /dest1/ differs (more files in src)

2.
rsync -ahv ~/ /dest1/
du -s differs and diff -r ~/ /dest1/ differs (more files in src)

3.
sudo rsync -ahv ~/ /dest2/

--> du -s differs and diff -r ~/ /dest2/ differs (more files in src)

4.
sudo cp -a ~/. /dest3/

--> du -s differs and diff -r ~/ /dest2/ differs (more files in src)

Then I ejecdted HD from ubuntu and compared folders via Windows:

dest3 and dest2 are identical
dest 1 contains one more file

What can I do to exactly mirror my home folder to a HD?

Comment: It might be possible that those files are created after the copy operation?

Comment: "What can I do to exactly mirror my home folder to a HD?" the first step would be using a different filesystem (e.g. ext4) because the file permissions are not preserved when using NTFS with Ubuntu's default fuse driver.

Comment: Copy-paste will not, by default, transfer hidden files and directories (those that start with `.`) and there will be quite a few in your home directory.

Comment: It's suspicious that none of these are working to create a copy. Perhaps your src has files that the process doesn't have permission to read, that would mean they couldn't be copied, and explain the multiple failings. Something like `find . ! -readable -exec ls -al '{}' \;` shows unreadable files (though for me that's because of the file being a link to a missing destination, mostly). Prefix as `sudo -u USERNAME find ...` using the username you're running the copy as in order to test readability by that user.

Comment: If you can see files in Windows what format are you using? You should be using a Linux format for any backup of Linux data, not any Windows format like NTFS or FAT32.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rsync` utility to clone a directory. Run:

```
sudo rsync -xrlptgoEvv --progress /home/user/source/ /home/user/dest/
```

To keep destination directory in fresh state, you can add `--delete` option - this will remove from destination directory files and directories which have been deleted in source directory since previous syncing, i.e.

```
sudo rsync -xrlptgoEvv --progress --delete /home/user/source/ /home/user/dest/
```

Another solution is `tar` with or without compression. Tar itself is just a multiple files "container". To create uncompressed tar-archive (archive file is larger, but creation process is faster) of a directory, issue the command:

```
tar pcvf archive.tar sourcedir/
```

Gzip compressed tar-archive (archive file is smaller, but creation process is slower) can be created with

```
tar pczvf archive.tar.gz sourcedir/
```

To extract such archives, use commands:

```
tar xvf archive.tar
tar xzvf archive.tar.gz
```

**Remark.** Use `sudo` before `tar` command if your directory contains files with restricted access for current user.

Comment: > ... a different filesystem (e.g. ext4) because the file permissions are not preserved when using NTFS ...   --> would it be possible to store it on a zip file on the NTFS backup HD? Which command do I need for backup and restore?

Comment: Thank you very much!  

> ...Use sudo before tar command if .... 

--> does this mean if I don't know I just use sudo in any case to make sure everything gets included?    And for restore: simply overwrite it directly to the home folder or to tmp first? What do you suggest?